# Ubuntu 18.04 does not wake up from the lock screen

Tags: lock-screen

I have recently installed a fresh copy of ubuntu 18.04 on a dell alienware 15 R4. Unfortunately, whenever I let the screen go black on the lock screen (or just lock my computer), there is no way of waking it up again. I have thus far resorted to cutting the power.

Based on other people experiencing similar (?) problems, I've looked through kern.log, which showed absolutely nothing (the last entries before the forced shutdown were from discord, which seems to be spamming entries the entire time it is active).

Also, based on another answer I've disabled USB suspension, which did not make any difference. Neither did enabling "USB wake support" in the BIOS.

Does anyone got a clue what on earth is going on here?

Comment: this behavior is only when system automatically locks the screen or when you press win+L key?

Comment: @PRATAP Both. The ones I've experienced thus far are booting to the login screen and waiting, having the system lock itself automatically after a set time period, and explicitly locking the device

Comment: i have experienced the same with Ubuntu 17.10 i guess and also at the initial release of Ubuntu 18.04 but now i am on Ubuntu 18.04 uptodate and when i press Win+L on my laptop keyboard or on my Desktop there is no problem. is your Ubuntu 18.04 up to date?

Comment: can you try installing any GDM3 Theme and see?

Comment: @PRATAP I have been keeping the system up-to-date through apt-get update / upgrade. I'll try installing a GDM3 theme

Comment: @PRATAP Installing a different theme did nothing. However, now that I'm sitting in a different location and the sun is shining on my screen, I noticed the problem is that the screen backlight isn't turning on.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Atleast we could confirm that GDM theme is not the one causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Dell XPS desktop with Nvidia Geforce GTX 1060 running latest Ubuntu 18.04. 
After I switched from using X.Org X Server video driver to NVIDIA proprietary driver the problem went away. 
Maybe try changing your video driver ?